# How to remove percent before converting it to integer

Tags: python, pandas, integer

I have a dataframe of 2 columns.I want to convert COUNT column to int.It keeps me giving value error:Unable to Parse string "0.58%" at position 0

```
METRIC      COUNT
Scans         125487
No Reads      2541
Diverts       54710
No Code%      0.58%
No Read%      1.25%


df['COUNT'] = df['COUNT'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

How can i remove % before conversion

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.strip`:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.col1.str.strip('%'))
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I am getting all NAN for other values that don't have %         df['COUNT'] = pd.to_numeric(df['COUNT'].str.strip('%'))

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I'm assuming that the 0.58% is read in as a string, meaning that the replace function will work to replace '%' with nothing, at which point, it can be converted to a number

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1','2','3%']})
df.col1.str.replace('%','').astype(float)
```

Comment: 0.58 is read as dtype:object and its giving me all NAN for values that don't have %